# How to add forms dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, html

Example speaks for it self:

```
function writeSpecialTabContentForTtm(){
        document.write('<div style="float:right;width:250px;min-height:200px;display:block;border-width: 1px 1px 1px">');
        document.write('<form  id="ttmsetpointrun" action="" style="text-align:right">');
        document.write('<input style="float:bottom;" type="submit" value="Move to Set Point" />');
        document.write('</form>');
        document.write('</div>');
```

How this should be done? There is a form that is chosen by user. To be precise, user choses a tab and when creating a tab the above function is called. This is something that is changed frequently, so it would be nice to write it in a separate file.

**edit:**

so, in my case it would be:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.style = "float:right;width:250px;min-height:200px;display:block;border-width: 1px 1px 1px";
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);  

var newform = document.createElement('form');
newform.id = "ttmsetpointrun"; 
newform.action="";
newform.style="text-align:right";
newdiv.appendChild(newform);

var newinput = document.createElement('input');
newinput.style = "float:bottom;";
newinput.type = "submit";
newinput.value = "Move to Set Point";
newform.appendChild(newinput);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create dynamic forms and elements in javascript is easy.

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); // Creates the div
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);          // Adds the div to body
```

After that, you can access newdiv and change attributes of it, such as

```
newdiv.className = "helloworld";
```

Comment: Can you use createElement in a nested way (see my edit above)? I mean, if I want to put "form" into "div", I just call newdiv.createElement('form')? Or is it document.body.newdiv.appendChild(newform)?

Comment: When creating elements, you use document.createElement(), this doesn't add the element to the web page. Then you will want to call newdiv.appendChild(theformyoucreated);

Comment: Ok, thanks. It almost works... is there "getCurrentChild" function? The first document.body.appendChild goes outside the current element. And my function does not know the current element (which is a child of body).

Comment: Not exactly sure what elements you are trying to get, but getElementsByTagName() might be useful. Or look into jQuery.

Comment: hmm, ok. There seems to be some problems that are related to the document.write. I am not sure in which order these are evaluated... The parent div (tab) that should contain the child div (form container) does not exists because I haven't written </div> to the document when I am appending it. So I have to change all document.write commands to use this appendChild for this to work... anyway now I know how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you "adding" the form dynamically like this in the first place?

IMHO you shouldn't be generating the HTML neither with `document.write` nor `document.createElement` in this case, since the actual form seems to be static.

Instead just add the form normally in your HTML

```
<form id="ttmsetpointrun">
    <input type="submit" value="Move to Set Point" />
</form>
```

but hide it in your CSS:

```
#ttmsetpointrun { display: none }
```

and then display it with JavaScript when the user clicks in the tab

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ttmsetpointrun').style.display = 'block'">Link</a>
```

If you want the form to be in a separate file, then include it using a server-side script (e.g. PHP).

Finally remember to use an external style sheet. If you put your styles into the HTML you are doing something wrong.

Comment: When the code was written for the first time, it was all static html. Then I modified that common tab content is parsed from xml file by javascript. This specialTabContent was just a quick hack that I am now fixing. The page is actually 90% javascript, and now I think I will get rid of the last of the html lines from the body.

Comment: @Juha Hmm, "Getting rid" of HTML sounds like a strange (and wrong) thing to do for a web page. Why would you want to do that? What is your scenario?

Comment: This is not a web page ;). Well, technically it is, as all the interpreters require the html etc. tags at the beginning. This is an UI for measurement devices. The other components catch the http-post commands in JSON form. Also it is very portable to any kind of device: smartphone, pc, mac, tablet...